# how to get redux state in setInterval

Tags: reactjs, redux, timer, setinterval, mapstatetoprops

I use Redux and react, and in timer after one second get value of redux state. Each time the Timer is executed, the value of the state does not change and it is the initial value .initial value in state is

```
00:00:00
```

note: The value in the state is correct, only in the timer the value is wrong and the initial value.

```
 CheckTheEndOfTheExam = setInterval(() => {
    handleSendWxamDataAfterEndTime();
 }, 60000);
```

```
 const handleSendWxamDataAfterEndTime = () => {    
       if (getTimeToAttendTheExamPage == data1.examParents[0].examParent_duration) {
           alert('زمان امتحان تمام شده است!!!');
        }
    }
```

```
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
    getTimeToAttendTheExamPage:getTimeToAttendTheExamPage,
});
```

Comment: It is because the callback passed into setInterval's closure only accesses the value in the first render and it doesn't have access to the new value in the next render

Comment: @Andrii Naidenko  What can I do to gain access to the new value? I know it can be used Ref for the state, can it be used here as well?

Comment: hope that can give a quick way to work around. @zahraei

Answer (score 1):

You can update the state using `setState callback` and call `handleSendWxamDataAfterEndTime` function inside the `useEffect` hook.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(0);

 CheckTheEndOfTheExam = setInterval(() => {
    setState(s => s + 1)
 }, 60000);
 
 useEffect(() => 
  {
    if (state > 0)
      handleSendWxamDataAfterEndTime()
  }, [state])
```